# NA values from a URL import

Tags: r, rcurl

Trying to load the XML data from this url
URL: https://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.xml.

```
# Load required library
library(RCurl)

# Define the URL
url <- "https://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.xml"

# Retrieve XML content from the URL
xml_content <- getURL(url)

# Load XML library
library(XML)

# Parse the XML content
xml_parsed <- xmlParse(xml_content)

# Extract data from XML and convert it to a data frame
data <- xmlToDataFrame(xml_parsed)

# Display the dimensions of the data
dim(data)
```

But my last row is all NA's. I know the dim is suppose to be 100 due to the number of senators per state but it's currently 101 due to that empty row.

```
> data[1:5]
            member_full    last_name     first_name party state
1        Baldwin (D-WI)      Baldwin          Tammy     D    WI
2       Barrasso (R-WY)     Barrasso           John     R    WY
3         Bennet (D-CO)       Bennet     Michael F.     D    CO
4      Blackburn (R-TN)    Blackburn         Marsha     R    TN
5     Blumenthal (D-CT)   Blumenthal        Richard     D    CT
6         Booker (D-NJ)       Booker        Cory A.     D    NJ
7        Boozman (R-AR)      Boozman           John     R    AR
8          Braun (R-IN)        Braun           Mike     R    IN
9          Britt (R-AL)        Britt     Katie Boyd     R    AL
10         Brown (D-OH)        Brown        Sherrod     D    OH
11          Budd (R-NC)         Budd            Ted     R    NC
12      Cantwell (D-WA)     Cantwell          Maria     D    WA
13        Capito (R-WV)       Capito  Shelley Moore     R    WV
14        Cardin (D-MD)       Cardin    Benjamin L.     D    MD
15        Carper (D-DE)       Carper      Thomas R.     D    DE
16         Casey (D-PA)        Casey Robert P., Jr.     D    PA
17       Cassidy (R-LA)      Cassidy           Bill     R    LA
18       Collins (R-ME)      Collins       Susan M.     R    ME
19         Coons (D-DE)        Coons Christopher A.     D    DE
20        Cornyn (R-TX)       Cornyn           John     R    TX
21  Cortez Masto (D-NV) Cortez Masto      Catherine     D    NV
22        Cotton (R-AR)       Cotton            Tom     R    AR
23        Cramer (R-ND)       Cramer          Kevin     R    ND
24         Crapo (R-ID)        Crapo           Mike     R    ID
25          Cruz (R-TX)         Cruz            Ted     R    TX
26        Daines (R-MT)       Daines          Steve     R    MT
27     Duckworth (D-IL)    Duckworth          Tammy     D    IL
28        Durbin (D-IL)       Durbin     Richard J.     D    IL
29         Ernst (R-IA)        Ernst           Joni     R    IA
30     Feinstein (D-CA)    Feinstein         Dianne     D    CA
31     Fetterman (D-PA)    Fetterman           John     D    PA
32       Fischer (R-NE)      Fischer            Deb     R    NE
33    Gillibrand (D-NY)   Gillibrand     Kirsten E.     D    NY
34        Graham (R-SC)       Graham        Lindsey     R    SC
35      Grassley (R-IA)     Grassley          Chuck     R    IA
36       Hagerty (R-TN)      Hagerty           Bill     R    TN
37        Hassan (D-NH)       Hassan  Margaret Wood     D    NH
38        Hawley (R-MO)       Hawley           Josh     R    MO
39      Heinrich (D-NM)     Heinrich         Martin     D    NM
40  Hickenlooper (D-CO) Hickenlooper        John W.     D    CO
41        Hirono (D-HI)       Hirono       Mazie K.     D    HI
42        Hoeven (R-ND)       Hoeven           John     R    ND
43    Hyde-Smith (R-MS)   Hyde-Smith          Cindy     R    MS
44       Johnson (R-WI)      Johnson            Ron     R    WI
45         Kaine (D-VA)        Kaine            Tim     D    VA
46         Kelly (D-AZ)        Kelly           Mark     D    AZ
47       Kennedy (R-LA)      Kennedy           John     R    LA
48          King (I-ME)         King  Angus S., Jr.     I    ME
49     Klobuchar (D-MN)    Klobuchar            Amy     D    MN
50      Lankford (R-OK)     Lankford          James     R    OK
51           Lee (R-UT)          Lee           Mike     R    UT
52        LujÃ¡n (D-NM)       LujÃ¡n        Ben Ray     D    NM
53        Lummis (R-WY)       Lummis     Cynthia M.     R    WY
54       Manchin (D-WV)      Manchin       Joe, III     D    WV
55        Markey (D-MA)       Markey      Edward J.     D    MA
56      Marshall (R-KS)     Marshall          Roger     R    KS
57     McConnell (R-KY)    McConnell          Mitch     R    KY
58      Menendez (D-NJ)     Menendez         Robert     D    NJ
59       Merkley (D-OR)      Merkley           Jeff     D    OR
60         Moran (R-KS)        Moran          Jerry     R    KS
61        Mullin (R-OK)       Mullin      Markwayne     R    OK
62     Murkowski (R-AK)    Murkowski           Lisa     R    AK
63        Murphy (D-CT)       Murphy    Christopher     D    CT
64        Murray (D-WA)       Murray          Patty     D    WA
65        Ossoff (D-GA)       Ossoff            Jon     D    GA
66       Padilla (D-CA)      Padilla           Alex     D    CA
67          Paul (R-KY)         Paul           Rand     R    KY
68        Peters (D-MI)       Peters        Gary C.     D    MI
69          Reed (D-RI)         Reed           Jack     D    RI
70      Ricketts (R-NE)     Ricketts           Pete     R    NE
71         Risch (R-ID)        Risch       James E.     R    ID
72        Romney (R-UT)       Romney           Mitt     R    UT
73         Rosen (D-NV)        Rosen          Jacky     D    NV
74        Rounds (R-SD)       Rounds           Mike     R    SD
75         Rubio (R-FL)        Rubio          Marco     R    FL
76       Sanders (I-VT)      Sanders        Bernard     I    VT
77        Schatz (D-HI)       Schatz          Brian     D    HI
78       Schmitt (R-MO)      Schmitt           Eric     R    MO
79       Schumer (D-NY)      Schumer     Charles E.     D    NY
80         Scott (R-FL)        Scott           Rick     R    FL
81         Scott (R-SC)        Scott            Tim     R    SC
82       Shaheen (D-NH)      Shaheen         Jeanne     D    NH
83        Sinema (I-AZ)       Sinema        Kyrsten     I    AZ
84         Smith (D-MN)        Smith           Tina     D    MN
85      Stabenow (D-MI)     Stabenow         Debbie     D    MI
86      Sullivan (R-AK)     Sullivan            Dan     R    AK
87        Tester (D-MT)       Tester            Jon     D    MT
88         Thune (R-SD)        Thune           John     R    SD
89        Tillis (R-NC)       Tillis           Thom     R    NC
90    Tuberville (R-AL)   Tuberville          Tommy     R    AL
91    Van Hollen (D-MD)   Van Hollen          Chris     D    MD
92         Vance (R-OH)        Vance           J.D.     R    OH
93        Warner (D-VA)       Warner        Mark R.     D    VA
94       Warnock (D-GA)      Warnock     Raphael G.     D    GA
95        Warren (D-MA)       Warren      Elizabeth     D    MA
96         Welch (D-VT)        Welch          Peter     D    VT
97    Whitehouse (D-RI)   Whitehouse        Sheldon     D    RI
98        Wicker (R-MS)       Wicker       Roger F.     R    MS
99         Wyden (D-OR)        Wyden            Ron     D    OR
100        Young (R-IN)        Young           Todd     R    IN
101                <NA>         <NA>           <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: This is political data and might be more appropriate e.g. for https://stat.stackexchange.com.